# Loading Zeilberger algorithm error in maxima

Tags: maxima

I try to load the Zeilberger algorithm in maxima but I get this error

> (%i1) load(Zeilberger);
>   file_search1: Zeilberger not found in file_search_maxima,file_search_lisp.
>       -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);

I tried [this](http://maxima-discuss.narkive.com/5tiUK7gj/i-cannot-load-zeilberger-package-nusum-zeilberger)

> (%i1)file_search_maxima: append(["/usr/share/maxima/.../share/contrib/Zeilberger"],file_search_maxima);
>   (%i2) load(Zeilberger);

but doesn't work.
the same thing for other packages.
NB: I use ubuntu

Comment: zeilberger, with little z

Comment: @MichaelO. same problem.

Comment: What is the result of `load(simplify_sum);` ? `simplify_sum` loads Zeilberger and other packages for simplification of sums. If you are interested in simplifying sums, then maybe try `simplify_sum` instead of Zeilberger.